# @DyanmoDBTypeConverted : problem loading complex document into java object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a complex object structure stored in AWS DynamoDB, what I want to load into a Java object.

Sample document to load:

```
{
  "anotherValue": 15.0,
  "anotherName": "myName",
  "d": {
    "bn": "d",
    "bt": 1570036012,
    "bu": "C",
    "e": [
      {
        "n": "1:48",
        "v": 0
      },
      {
        "n": "1:49",
        "v": 0
      },
      {
        "n": "1:50",
        "v": 34.5
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I created a java object with `@DynamoDBDocument` annotation where I want to represent the `d` document, also added a `@DynamoDBTypeConverted` annotation pointing to the implemented converter:

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName="d")
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyDTypeConverter.class)
private MyDType dType;
```

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public static class MyDType { ... }
```

```
public static class  MyDTypeConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<Map<String, Object>, MyDType> { ... }
```

However I still get an exception:
`DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted`

Can you point me to the right direction how I can convert/unconvert documents like the example above?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @DynamoDBDocument annotation from class MyDType.